# ssh terminal session getting times out, broken pipe appears

Tags: gnome-terminal, sshd

SSH connection to AMI Instance gets terminate often. 
i do open by vi /etc/ssh/sshd_config but it seems to empty.

what configuration needs to be modified so that we could eliminate the remote shell from being terminated.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably unrelated to AWS. I have had sessions open for days without interruption. Does this happen if you connect to other services?

The only time I have had this problem is when a local ADSL modem/router was behaving badly. Replacing the router completely solved the problem. Perhaps you could get hold of a different router to try it.

Answer (score 0):

Some router between the client and the server may be dropping the session when it goes too long without activity. Try setting the **ServerAliveInterval** or **TCPKeepAlive** options for `ssh`. These will cause ssh to send something to the server at regular intervals to keep the connection from being completely idle. [Here is a copy of the ssh config file documentation.](http://www.manpagez.com/man/5/ssh_config/)